# Problem data truncated in mysql-PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem:

> Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column

I got a form with a value coming from a text field : price.

When I put a decimal like : 45,56 ( French format)

My MySQL column type is a float.

Could someone help please ?

Comment: If you expect the users to enter the data with a comma, before using the data replace the comma with a decimal point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

float data must be saved with a . "Dot" instead of a , "comma". `45.56`

so before to save the data in the mysql, be sure that the format is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You should *never* use floating-point types for currency if  you care about precision. You'll experience all sorts of weird rounding and comparison errors. For more information, see [the Wikipedia page on Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

DECIMAL would suit your needs better -- [from the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/numeric-types.html):

> The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types [...] are used to store values for which it is important to preserve exact precision, ***for example with monetary data***."

DECIMAL(15,2) would be a good idea, but it doesn't change that currency formatting runs foul of storing numbers -- you need to change the comma to a decimal before the value will be accepted into a column that is a numeric data type.

Comment: Wow! Never thought of that, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the comma `,` as a decimal separator, but a dot `.`

e.g. 45.56

Not only are you getting a warning, it also doesn't save the decimals. :)

Answer (score 0):

it happens when value you are inserting doesnt comes under specified data type for the specific column in mysql.

it happened to me when i was trying to insert date as "2013-02-31" in column named date and data type set to date.
so 2013-02-31 is not valid date and thats why it gives error.